# VB.NET Use WebRequest to check if URI is valid

Tags: vb.net, httpwebresponse

Looking for the best way to determine if a URI exists in VB.NET without downloading the actual content. `System.IO.FileExists`/`My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists` can be used locally to determine if a file exists, is there an equivalent for the Web?

Currently I am using a `HttpWebRequest` to check URI existance using the `ResponseStream`. This populates the stream if the target does exist and throws an exception if it doesn't. The function is being expanded to also check for PDF files (typically 5MB +), images, etc and it will be a waste of time/bandwidth to actually populate the content into a stream.

In the case of "Success" (the target does exist) I do not wish to download the file or page, simply to end up with a Boolean which indicates the whether something exists at the end of this URI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is in VB.NET.  Make sure that your addresses start with **http://** or **https://**.

```
Public Function CheckAddress(ByVal URL As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Note: If you are in an active directory intranet environment you'll probably need this line of code between the "Dim request" and "Dim response" line: Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Answer (score 5):

```
        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req;// Prepare request
            response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            HttpWebResponse exResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            response = exResponse;                
        }
```

And now yo can just check `responce.StatusCode`